# How to get this session working in Google login php?

Tags: php, google-signin

I am logging a user using Google login. I have included all the necessary files needed for Google login. I have created a PHP script for log-in. I have all my authentication and redirection info in place. However, I do not understand why am I not getting email field which I am getting from googleClient in my session. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$google_client_id       = '#########.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$google_client_secret   = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$google_redirect_url    = 'http://localhost/project/profile.php';
$google_developer_key   = '';

//include google api files
require_once '../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

session_start();

$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);

$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

if (isset($_REQUEST['reset'])) 
{
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $gClient->revokeToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{ 
    $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    return;
}


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{ 
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}


if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) 
{
      //Get user details if user is logged in
      $user                 = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
      $user_id              = $user['id'];
      $user_name            = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $email                = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      $profile_url          = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
      $profile_image_url    = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
      $personMarkup         = "$email<div><img src='$profile_image_url?sz=50'></div>";
      $_SESSION['token']    = $gClient->getAccessToken();
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
}
else 
{
    //get google login url
    $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}

?>
```

My profile.php looks like this -

It results in -
Notice: Undefined index: email on line 4

After this script runs, the control jumps to the next page where it says that email is not found in session. Should I create a new Google_Client()? Whats the proper way to do this series of interaction after login?

Comment: Do I need to include these lines in every page .. ??

$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);

Please help someone.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate on your local server?

Comment: Yes I am authenticating the user on my local server

Comment: I am getting this ... Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'redirect_uri_mismatch''

Comment: Do I need to chain the URIs or something? Tell me something man.

Comment: I would suggest to move your entire source code over any development server which is accessible over internet and then check Google authentication..

Comment: It wont work on your local machine i.e. localhost..

Comment: Ok.. I will move it ASAP. Atleast tell me.. what I am doing is right ?

Comment: I am creating an instance of GoogleClient on every page; is it right? Do I need to specify redirect-urls everywhere .. or I guess the token should handle everything else.

Comment: I assume token will handle everything as my team member did the same, I have not done yet personally..

Comment: If you find any links related or a github project. Please help me. Its brain-draining stuff. No useful things on Google as well as Stackoverflow is useless on this topic. Nobody entertains it. :X

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all it will work on localhost, no problem. Because I have just created google and facebook login and it works fine.
2. you need to add Google ClientID and Client secret key from the console developer google where you have created web app and ouath key.

In main Login page you can redirect to another page...

```
  /*!  \brief Configure the client object
 * Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens
 */
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();      /**< retrieve the access token with the getAccessToken method */
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));  /**<  Redirect the user to $auth_url:   */
}
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);   /**<  apply an access token to a new Google_Client object */
}

$authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl(); /**< Generate a URL to request access from Google's OAuth 2.0 server */
```

Try this..

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
!(set($_GET['code'])) { 
$gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']); 
$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken(); /**< retrieve the access token with the getAccessToken method */ 
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); /**< Redirect the user to $auth_url: */ } 
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']); /**< apply an access token to a new Google_Client object */ 
})
```